# Any free OPC HDA client tools suitable for scripting?

Tags: opc

I've been searching for a while now and I was unable to find a free `OPC HDA` client tool capable of retrieving data from an `OPC HDA` server between two timestamps based on a list of tags in a programmable/scripting way. I'm interested into something similar to `OpenOPC` (which handles only `DA` communication and is a `python` wrapper). I'm not necessarily looking for a `python OPC HDA` toolkit but would be nice.

Comment: http://openopc.sourceforge.net/api.html ?

Comment: @CamilleG. openopc works only with DA, not HDA (historical data access).